# Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined (Bootstrap Typeahead)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

i'm trying to make a typeahead code. But there's an issu like that:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "system/json.php",
  success: function(cevap){
    var jsonString = '['+cevap+']';

    var jsonObj = $.parseJSON(jsonString);
    var sourceArr = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++) {
   sourceArr.push(jsonObj[i].label);
    }

$(".my-auto-complete").typeahead({
   source: sourceArr
});

}
});
```

How can i fix it? i couldn't understand how to configure javascript based configuration about typeahead

edit: json.php is like that:

```
{"51eb585b8b3b5b531c0012be":{"_id":{"$id":"51eb585b8b3b5b531c0012be"},"takim":"Mechelen"},"51eb585b8b3b5b531c0012c5":{"_id":{"$id":"51eb585b8b3b5b531c0012c5"}
```

Comment: what is the value of `cevap`?

Comment: ups sorry. this is json like that: {"51eb585b8b3b5b531c0012be":{"_id":{"$id":"51eb585b8b3b5b531c0012be"},"takim":"Mechelen"},"51eb585b8b3b5b531c0012c5":{"_id":{"$id":"51eb585b8b3b5b531c0012c5"}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "system/json.php",
  success: function(cevap){
    var jsonString = '['+cevap+']';

    var jsonObj = $.parseJSON(jsonString);
    var sourceArr = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++) {
      sourceArr.push(jsonObj[i].label);
    }
    typeahead = $('.my-auto-complete').data('typeahead');
    typeahead.source = sourceArr;
  }
});

$(".my-auto-complete").typeahead();
```

Comment: thx but there is an other error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined :Ss

Comment: That is likely occurring in:

var jsonObj = $.parseJSON(jsonString);

for some reason, maybe based on what's being returned in the cevap var.